# Regression with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, predictive-modeling

I am trying to train a tensorflow model for regression analysis using this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression.

My dataset is this:

```
0         1         2         3  ...  Activity  Month  Day  Duration
0 -0.239542 -0.013517  0.035927  0.071829  ...         1      3   10       5.0
1 -0.202316  0.022236  0.062185  0.083951  ...         2      3   10       5.0
2 -0.254355  0.092587  0.026296  0.149497  ...         3      3   10       5.0
3 -0.097311 -0.224233 -0.008356 -0.134513  ...         4      3   10       5.0
4 -0.085504 -0.083839  0.068088 -0.109697  ...         5      3   10       5.0
```

There are 46 more columns between 3 and Activity all with values  between -1 and 1. The thing to predict is the duration column which is the last one. It ranges from 1 to 35.

The code I used is this:

```
# Train test validation split
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(data.loc[:, data.columns != 'Duration'], data['Duration'], test_size=0.2)
trainX, valX, trainY, valY = train_test_split(trainX, trainY, test_size=0.2)

#Convert various splits into tensors
trainX = tf.convert_to_tensor(trainX)
trainY = tf.convert_to_tensor(trainY)

valX = tf.convert_to_tensor(valX)
valY = tf.convert_to_tensor(valY)

testX = tf.convert_to_tensor(testX)
testY = tf.convert_to_tensor(testY)

normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(np.array((data.loc[:, data.columns != "Duration"])))

#Define Model
duration_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(128,  kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
])
duration_model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001),
                       loss='mean_absolute_error')

history = duration_model.fit(
    trainX,
    trainY,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(valX, valY)
)
```

My loss is too high I am getting a loss of 10 so far even with 1000 epochs.

Comment: is your target variable "duration" a float value?

Comment: `learning_rate` is too small. Start with the default

Comment: Yes and no. It is a continuous value can be float but current the values are just integers